# JSON Serializer C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am developing online aircraft sales system.

But I have a problem..

A URL address have:

```
string urlFlightSearch = "https://api.iati.com/rest/flightSearch/" + ado.iatiKod + "";
```

A have class "iati.cs" in codes

```
public class iati
{
    public class flightSearch
    {
        public string fromAirport { get; set; }
        public bool allinFromCity { get; set; }
        public string toAirport { get; set; }
        public string fromDate { get; set; }
        public string returnDate { get; set; }
        public string adult { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
    }
    public class Leg
    {
        public string flightNo { get; set; }
        public string aircraft { get; set; }
        public string operatorCode { get; set; }
        public string operatorName { get; set; }
        public string departureAirport { get; set; }
        public string departureTime { get; set; }
        public string departureAirportName { get; set; }
        public string departureCityName { get; set; }
        public string arrivalAirport { get; set; }
        public string arrivalTime { get; set; }
        public string arrivalAirportName { get; set; }
        public string arrivalCityName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Detail
    {
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double serviceFee { get; set; }
        public double tax { get; set; }
        public int suplement { get; set; }
    }
    public class Fare
    {
        public double totalSingleAdultFare { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<string> segmentNames { get; set; }
        public int freeSeatCount { get; set; }
        public Detail detail { get; set; }
    }
    public class Flight
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string providerKey { get; set; }
        public string pricingType { get; set; }
        public int packageId { get; set; }
        public List<Leg> legs { get; set; }
        public List<Fare> fares { get; set; }
        public int segmentCount { get; set; }
        public int baggage { get; set; }
        public int flightTimeHour { get; set; }
        public int flightTimeMinute { get; set; }
        public int layoverTime { get; set; }
        public bool hasCip { get; set; }
        public bool canBook { get; set; }
        public bool canRezerve { get; set; }
        public bool dayCross { get; set; }
        public bool returnFlight { get; set; }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string searchId { get; set; }
        public List<Flight> flights { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And posting...

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

iati.flightSearch search = new iati.flightSearch()
{
    fromAirport = "IST",
    allinFromCity = true,
    toAirport = "AYT",
    fromDate = "2013-12-23",
    returnDate = "2013-12-30",
    adult = "1",
    currency = "EUR"
};

var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(search);
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
string result = wc.UploadString(urlFlightSearch, serializedResult);
iati.Flight flight = serializer.Deserialize<iati.Flight>(result);
```

But the result returned is always coming up empty.

[image: See this image here]

Regards.

Comment: The web service call is irrelevant. Please trim down the code to `string result = "some example input"; iati.Flight flight = serializer.Deserialize<iati.Flight>(result);`.

Comment: This won't directly answer your question, but I had to serialize ArrayList to json and I used this class : http://techblog.procurios.nl/l/nl/library/download/14610. Care, in `SerializeValue` method, `DateTime` objects are not handled.

Comment: try to debug your service if possible or see you request using jsfiddler that will show you what you are posting and what you are getting as output

Comment: thanks but `List<iati.Result> flights = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<iati.Result>>(result)`; 

Problem : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Answer (score 0):

use Newtonsoft

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);